# Dynamically inserting rows in HTML table with JQuery that cannot be targeted

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table, nodes

I am having trouble targeting rows newly created by hitting "Enter" with the code below. If I felt so inclined, I would like to keep hitting "Enter" to create new rows; however, hitting enter twice will only produce a maximum of one new row (from the original HTML rows). In attempt to debug the situation, I used a click event listener to console log the nodes associated with the table and found it odd that there are text nodes in between every row from the native HTML; however, these text nodes are not dynamically generated with every new row. Are these text nodes required for an HTML table to function properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("tr").on("keydown", "input", function(){
                keyDownLocation = this.selectionStart;
            });

            $("tr").on("keyup", "input", function(e){
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                    var tempSelect = this.value.substr(this.selectionStart);
                    this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.selectionStart);
                    $(this).parent().parent().after('<tr><td class="checkbox-td"><input type="checkbox" name="checklist-list" class="checkbox-box"></td><td class="item-td"><input class="input-item" type="text" value="' + tempSelect + '"></td></tr>');
                    $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".input-item").focus();
                }
            });

            $("tr").on("click", "input", function(){
                console.log($(this));
                console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent()[0].childNodes);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="checklist-list" class="checkbox-box"></th>
                <th>Item</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="checkbox-td"><input type="checkbox" name="checklist-list" class="checkbox-box"></td>
                <td class="item-td"><input class="input-item" type="text" value="Artificial"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="checkbox-td"><input type="checkbox" name="checklist-list" class="checkbox-box"></td>
                <td class="item-td"><input class="input-item" type="text" value="Broken"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="checkbox-td"><input type="checkbox" name="checklist-list" class="checkbox-box"></td>
                <td class="item-td"><input class="input-item" type="text" value="Casual"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issues is, the `.on()` is not attaching to the dynamically created rows. You need to change it to `$("#myTable").on("keyup", "tr td input", function(){});`

Comment: If I had the fortune of finding that post, I might not have found the realized the nuance of the static ancestor element (before the "on" method) vs the targeted dynamically created element (after the on method). I would argue that you are correct that there is a fair amount of overlap between this question and the one you reference. I'm still curious to know why the text child nodes (between <tr> nodes) aren't being dynamically generated JQuery as they are automatically generated by the original HTML. Thank you for your help, Kramb!

Comment: The reason is because the event handler is bound to every `tr` element on the page at the time the page loads. If you create a `tr` element after page load, like you do in the keyup event, then they are new to the DOM and do not have the same handlers as the original `tr`s. If you attach it to the table, then the handler says that ALL `tr`s that I contain must use this handler. This includes `tr`s generated after the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are, it's just that your delegation selector is wrong. The `tr` you insert isn't bound like the others at DOM ready... so bind the to the `tbody` that's already there, then look up the `tr`

```
$("tbody").on("keydown", "tr input", function(){


$("tbody").on("keyup", "tr input", function(e){


$("tbody").on("click", "tr input", function(){
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ooavyybm/

Comment: Thank you, tymeJV! I understand the functionality of the "on" method quite a bit better now.